# Product topology, continuity of a function with a cartesian product as domain

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $I$ be a set and for each $i\in I$ let $(X_i,T_i)$ be a topological space. Consider the cartesian product $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$, endowed with the product topology. In addition, let $(Y,T)$ be a topological space. I want to prove that a function $f\colon\prod_{i\in I}X_i\to Y$ is continuous in a point $(a_i)_{i\in I}\in\prod_{i\in I}X_i$.

Consider the functions
$g_i\colon X_i\to\prod_{i\in I}X_i$

defined by

\begin{align}g_i(x)\colon I&\to\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\\
j&\mapsto\begin{cases}x&\text{for i=j}\\ a_j&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
\end{align}

If for all $i\in I$ $f\circ g_i$ is continuous in $a_i$, does that imply that f is continuous?

If the answer is yes, i'd like to see the prove.

Comment: Am I correct that $g_i$ is the identity on the $i^\text{th}$ factor, but constant ($a_j$) on the $j\text{th}$ factor?

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simple counter-example:
Consider the function
\begin{align*}
f\colon\mathbb{R}^2&\to\mathbb{R}\\
(x,y)&\mapsto\begin{cases}0&\text{for }(x,y)=0\\\frac{x\cdot y}{x^2+y^2}&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
\end{align*}
The functions
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{R}&\to\mathbb{R}\\
x&\mapsto f(x,0)=0
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{R}&\to\mathbb{R}\\
y&\mapsto f(0,y)=0
\end{align*}
are continuous. But $f$ is not continuous at $0$, because
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\neq f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=0.
\end{equation*}